# Screen empty after rotation

Tags: android, kotlin, rotation, viewmodel, viewmodel-savedstate

I need to handle screen rotation so I read about saved state and I tried to implement it bit I cant !

here is the fragment screen :

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ImagePickerFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var imagePickerBinding: FragmentImagePickerBinding
    private val imagePickerViewModel: ImagePickerViewModel by viewModels {
        SavedStateViewModelFactory(activity?.applicationContext as Application, this)
    }
    private lateinit var imagePickerAdapter: ImagePickerAdapter


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        imagePickerBinding = FragmentImagePickerBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        imagePickerBinding.lifecycleOwner = this
        observeImageList()
        observeSearchText()
        observeImageClicked()


        return imagePickerBinding.root
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        imagePickerViewModel.trigger()
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }
private fun observeImageList() {
    imagePickerViewModel.observeImageListData.observe(
        viewLifecycleOwner,
        EventObserver { imageList ->
            initializeImageList(imageList)
        })
}
```

So here I should initialize viewModel with savedstate but this getting error :

```
09-23 13:10:38.621 26928-26928/com.payback.imagepicker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.payback.imagepicker, PID: 26928
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.payback.imagepicker/com.payback.imagepicker.manager.base.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.payback.imagepicker.presentation.ui.image_picker.ImagePickerViewModel
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.payback.imagepicker.presentation.ui.image_picker.ImagePickerViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:221)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:278)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:112)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:54)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:41)
        at com.payback.imagepicker.presentation.ui.image_picker.ImagePickerFragment.getImagePickerViewModel(ImagePickerFragment.kt:30)
        at com.payback.imagepicker.presentation.ui.image_picker.ImagePickerFragment.observeImageList(ImagePickerFragment.kt:73)
        at com.payback.imagepicker.presentation.ui.image_picker.ImagePickerFragment.onCreateView(ImagePickerFragment.kt:45)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:3065)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2988)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:502)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.payback.imagepicker.presentation.ui.image_picker.ImagePickerViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFact
09-23 13:15:38.690 26928-26928/com.payback.imagepicker I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26928 SIG: 9
```

And this is My view model :

```
@HiltViewModel
class ImagePickerViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val imageListUseCase: ImageListUseCase,
    private val responseManager: ResponseManager,
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : BaseViewModel() {

    private val _observeImageListData :
        MutableLiveData<Event<ArrayList<Image>>> = savedStateHandle.getLiveData("key")

  fun trigger() {
        savedStateHandle.set("key", _observeImageClicked.value)
    }
```

Please can any one help me ? I cant understand it well or implement it right so what's wrong?

Comment: Try using a viewmodel and saving the data in the viewmodel, it will be a lot easier to handle the configuration changes as the viewmodel has its own lifecycle state.

Comment: Please attach full stack trace. Usually the real cause is noted in few lines of that, usually right after the "caused by..."

Comment: Can you show me example please ? 
@Saugat Jonchhen

Comment: Check it @ 
Maroš Šeleng